# JBoss7 server becomes inaccessible after 3 days

Tags: web-applications, jboss7.x, java-7

I have a server on which JBoss 7 runs. If I don't access the web application deployed on this server for a period of 3 or more days, then JBoss stops responding and hangs in the browser. Is there any configuration that needs to be set to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Have a look at the log files. It could be memory or something.

Comment: There's no errors in either the server log or the access log. I'm wondering if there's some kind of configuration in standalone.xml that needs to be changed?

Comment: I have Jboss servers running at home all the time. (servers in plural but it's only one that I up date/grade every now and again). I have a few apps that we use at home and some times we spend a few days without using it but never had problems like yours. it could be your hardware going to sleep due to inactivity or something.

Comment: Thanks Desorder. Could you please send me one of your standalone.xml files so I can compare it against my configuration?

Comment: My current stable Jboss is the 7.1 final and I'm using the standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file out of the box. I can send it to you in like 3 hours out (that is when I leave work and go home) but I can ensure you if you download that same version, it will be the same file

Comment: Windows server with default jvm settings that came with server?